# duplicate one element from php array

Tags: php, arrays, duplicate-data

how i can duplicate one element from array:

for example, i have this array:

```
Array
(
    [LRDEPN] => 0008.jpg
    [OABCFT] => 0030.jpg
    [SIFCFJ] => 0011.jpg
    [KEMOMD] => 0022.jpg
    [DHORLN] => 0026.jpg
    [AHFUFB] => 0029.jpg
)
```

if i want to duplicate this: 0011.jpg , how to proceed?

i want to get this:

```
Array
(
    [LRDEPN] => 0008.jpg
    [OABCFT] => 0030.jpg
    [SIFCFJ] => 0011.jpg
    [NEWKEY] => 0011.jpg
    [KEMOMD] => 0022.jpg
    [DHORLN] => 0026.jpg
    [AHFUFB] => 0029.jpg
)
```

Comment: You can't have two array elements with the same key, explain better what you need to do.

Comment: i want to duplicate one element! generate a new key with the value i want to duplicate!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like the following, change the uniqid() function to yours:

```
<?php

$a=array(
    'LRDEPN' => '0008.jpg',
    'OABCFT' => '0030.jpg',
    'SIFCFJ' => '0011.jpg',
    'KEMOMD' => '0022.jpg',
    'DHORLN' => '0026.jpg',
    'AHFUFB' => '0029.jpg'
);

$i='0011.jpg';

$newArray=array();
foreach($a as $k=>$v){
    $newArray[$k]=$v;
    if($v==$i) $newArray[uniqid()]=$v;
}

print_r($newArray);

?>
```

Which gets you:

```
Array
(
    [LRDEPN] => 0008.jpg
    [OABCFT] => 0030.jpg
    [SIFCFJ] => 0011.jpg
    [4bd014ebf3351] => 0011.jpg
    [KEMOMD] => 0022.jpg
    [DHORLN] => 0026.jpg
    [AHFUFB] => 0029.jpg
)
```

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT:**

Looks like you modified your question :)

If you want to have a `new` key with the duplicated value you can do:

```
$array_name['NEWKEY'] = $array_name['SIFCFJ']
```

**Old answer:**

You cannot.

An array cannot have multiple values with same key.

```
$arr = array();
$arr['foo'] = 'bar1';
$arr['foo'] = 'bar2'; // this will wipe out bar1
```

And if you try to duplicate:

```
$arr = array();
$arr['foo'] = 'bar1';
$arr['foo'] = 'bar1';
```

you'll be overwriting the value `bar1` associated with key `foo` with `bar1` itself. The array will have `1` key value pair not `2`.

Comment: ok!i understand, i edited the question! i will generate a new key, but i want the value to be the same!

Comment: @robertdd: Having a new key with the old value is possible. I've updated my answer.

Comment: how i cand add the $array_name['NEWKEY'] right after $array_name['SIFCFJ']
?

Answer (score 0):

```
$arr['newkey'] = $arr['oldkey'];
natsort($arr);
```